# Change z-index on element width

Tags: jquery

I have problem with z-index between two elements. When blue box expand it should go over orange and orange over blue. I decided to go with add class when box expand...
http://jsfiddle.net/RRMLU/2/

```
function blue() {
if ($("#blue").width() > 350) {
    $(this).addClass('test')

}
else {
    $(this).removeClass('test')
}
$("#blue").delay( 0 )
    .animate({"height": "+=15px", "width": "+=25px", },1000, 'swing');
$("#blue").delay( 500 )
    .css({"position":"absolute"})
    .animate({"height": "-=15px", "width": "-=25px"},1000, 'swing', blue)
$("#blue").delay( 1500 )
```

}

I tried with this code, but with no luck... :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `z-index` of an element in jQuery using this: `$('#blue').zIndex(1);`.  Try using this when the boxes are animated.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you trying to do, and your code looks a bit messi...

i addes the class .test with a z-index...

and also called the blue() function on hovering

http://jsfiddle.net/EXKP2/

```
$("#blue").hover(function(){
        $(this)
        .animate({"height": "280px", "width": "430px"},1000, 'swing', blue)
        .css({"box-shadow":"1px 3px 3px #333"});
        $(this).stop(true,false);
 },
    function() {
        $(this)
        .animate({"height": "218px", "width": "405px"},1000, 'swing', blue)
        .css({"box-shadow":"none"});
        $(this).clearQueue();
});
```